# Variable scope and sharing information without global variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have:

```
function firstFunction(){
    var counter = 0;
    secondFunction();
    secondFunction();
    secondFunction();
    secondFunction();
}
function secondFunction(){
    counter++;
}
```

I get an error because of the local scope of the variable, but how else am I to do something like this without using global variables?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way is to use a closure:

```
(function() {
    var counter = 0;

    function firstFunction() {
        secondFunction();
        secondFunction();
        secondFunction();
        secondFunction();
    }

    function secondFunction() {
        counter++;
    }
})();
```

Alternately, you could pass in the value of `counter` to `secondFunction`, like this:

```
function firstFunction() {
    var counter = 0;
    counter = secondFunction(counter);
    counter = secondFunction(counter);
    counter = secondFunction(counter);
    counter = secondFunction(counter);
}

function secondFunction(counter) {
    return ++counter;
}
```

Comment: That's cool, can I still call firstFunction() from wherever else in my code?

Comment: As long as "wherever else" is within the closure, yes. If you wanted to call the function from outside the closure, add this line to the end of the closure: `window.firstFunction = firstFunction;`

Comment: As long as "wherever else" is within scope, whether or not a closure exists.

Comment: True, that's true. I just assumed that was obvious, though.

Answer (score 1):

Use Object to pass counter by reference

```
   function firstFunction() {

        var myObj = new Object();
        myObj.counter = 0;

        secondFunction(myObj);
        secondFunction(myObj);
        secondFunction(myObj);
        secondFunction(myObj);

    }

    function secondFunction(obj) {
        obj.counter++;
    }
```

Comment: You needn't use an object to pass `counter` along.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville Isn't passing just counter, passes it by value and change doesn't persist outside the function?

Comment: Yeah, that's right. To get around that you could return `counter`. However, I must say, I do like this code pattern. I haven't seen it before. However, I would recommend using an object literal instead: `var counterHolder = {counter: 0};`

Comment: Please, don't use explicit constructor calls for objects that have a literal notation: `new Object();`, `new Object(123);` and `new Object('a string');` might return something unexpected... much like `new Array(2)` vs `new Array('2')` or `new Array(2,3,1)`

Comment: @Bergi Please *DO NOT* edit my code for anything but aesthetics and format. If you don't agree with it - comment on it or downvote it. But what was here after your edit - was not my solution.

Comment: Sorry if you felt the edit was too large. Actually I did upvote it and wanted to fix the little imprecisenesses :-) Using the object literal was already commented twice, and I thought it *was* aestetics…

Answer (score 1):

Since primitive types (such as integers and strings) in javascript are passed by value, but objects are passed by reference, you need to use an object:

```
// passing primitive type
var counter = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 4; ++i) { 
    secondFunction(counter);
}
alert(counter); // 0
function secondFunction(counter) {
    counter++;
}

// passing object
var obj = { counter: 0 }
for (var i = 0; i < 4; ++i) { 
    secondFunction(obj);
}
alert(obj.counter); // 4
function secondFunction(obj) {
    obj.counter++;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MpVqQ/2/

This way you can achieve what you want without using global variables.

Comment: _everything_ is passed by value in JS, no variable ever holds an object. The value of your variable `obj` isn't the object literal, it's value is a reference. Also: functions are objects, and every function call creates a call-object (which holds the scope), that's a far better, safer and more controlled way to go about your business 99.99% of the time

Comment: In your example you forgot to *pass* the object, you could have used a primitive variable as well :-)

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to Elliot Bonneville's answer, you can also do this:

```
var firstFunction = (function()
{
    var counter = 0,
    secondFunction = function
    {
        counter++;
    };
    return function()
    {
        counter = 0;//initialize counter to 0
        secondFunction();
        return counter;
    };
};
console.log(firstFunction());//logs 1, because counter was set to 1 and returned
```

This is all getting a bit much, but google *"JavaScript module pattern"* and look into it. You'll soon find out what makes this code tick:

```
var counterModule = (function()
{
    var counter = 0,
    secondFunction = function
    {
        counter++;
    },
    firstFunction = function()
    {
        counter = 0;//initialize counter to 0
        secondFunction();
    },
    getCounter = function()
    {
        return counter;
    }
    setCounter = function(val)
    {
        counter = +(val);
    };
    return {firstFunction: firstFunction,
            getCounter: getCounter,
            setCounter: setCounter};
};
console.log(counterModule.firstFunction());//undefined
console.log(counterModule.getCounter());//1
console.log(counterModule.secondFunction());//ERROR
```

It's all about exposure of certain closure variables... Keep working at it, this is an important pattern to understand, I promise!

Comment: Why the down-vote... as always: I don't mind, provided the DV'er explains what's wrong with my answer